# In Atlassian Jira 4.1.2 how can I make a profile that may only view users of the system?

Tags: jira

Experience with Jira is based on what I have seen from clicking through the project. There is no knowledge transfer as all people who knew this customized system left over a year ago.
As for the Atlassian PDF guide, it is not able to assist because the feature to add users and manage the users in Jira have been removed. An external LDAP system is where the users are managed.
I can view the User Browser and see users and do some editing of a profile and even delete the user from a navigation link in the footer.

But the real question at hand is, what do I need to do in order to 
A. Assign users to an Organization Role that only allows them
   1: A view only mode of the users in that Organization
   2: View the details of the user and that users permissions/roles given

I've been looking for a few days now and just keep running into brick walls.
Thank you.
The upgrading of the system to the new version is not an option due to the extensive undocumented modifications made to Jira. It has been tried 3 times in the past 2 years without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering based on JIRA 5.2 and higher experience.

Only place to see list of users is User Manager and you need to be JIRA admin to access it. So it's not a solution for you.

I searched for addon doing this but no luck. Moreover your JIRA is too old to be supported by addon providers.

The same story with JIRA REST API. Looks like for JIRA 4.1 you need to use JIRA REST 1.0 (current is 2.0) and I can not find docs for it.

I believe it's possible to write the addon to accomplish what you need but again it's not smart to invest in obsolete JIRA.

The most right solution is still migrate to the newest version of JIRA. Maybe you need abandon the undocumented changes or rewrite them into JIRA addons. It will not be easy and it can be costly but looks like you do not have too many options.

Comment: Volodymyr, Thank you for this information. It was more of what I have been thinking and trying to tell the project manager. Perhaps with feedback such as this they'll listen a little more, but then again I doubt it. Really appreciate your time in your response.

Answer (score 0):

Task has been abandoned.

No answer to bad implementation and poor engineering practices when one is to continue to follow them.

I'd delete the post entirely but I'd rather give credit to the few that tried to provide some insight. Thanks again.